# How to check column in array in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sorry if the topic name is not reasonable.

I have a column in mySql with value (10,11,12), it's a string, like this

[image]

And I have an array to check, how can select this row if array contains any one value 10, 11 or 12. For example:

```
array(3,4,11) - choose
array(5,6,7) - not choose
array(11,8,10) - choose
```

Thank you!

Comment: you should normalize you data ..

Comment: try `FIND_IN_SET()`

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() worked fine. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query :

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(10, custom_categories) 
      OR FIND_IN_SET(11, custom_categories) 
      OR FIND_IN_SET(12, custom_categories);
```

For More Detail : **[Read](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-find_in_set-function.php)**

Comment: To check against an array though you have to iterate it and run a query for each item

Comment: @Tumtum, check the OP's screen shot its not array , its just simple comma separated values.

Comment: Yes, but he's running it against a PHP array as well if I am not mistaken

Comment: @Tumtum, in that case user needs to create a where condition dynamic and make it look like updated answer